# Get The Top 10 Values of a Map C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a std::map by value before output & destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367429/sorting-a-stdmap-by-value-before-output-destroy)

```
map<string, int> Hosts;
```

Which contain a host and the amount of times that host was accessed.

How can I get the top X values of that map?

Comment: I found that after I posted it sadly, I'm in the process of trying it.

Comment: After some modification (changing the for to only go to map.size()) it works perfect. Could people please vote to delete?

Comment: It's not a problem if the topic stays. Maybe, it'll help others as it'll come in search results!

Comment: if you didn't found it right away, it means that one more pointer to the original subject is worth keeping around. So we'll just close it as duplicate, so that people are redirected :)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>` and use `std::sort` providing your own `compare` function (or functor), that would solve this problem more easily. Also you use `std::map` which sorts the elements by their key. I think you don't need container which sorts by key (`string`), but by value (`int`).

EDIT: I just noticed that even the possible duplicate does the same thing as I said. It uses `std::vector`, so you also use this as:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> Hosts; //Use this instead of map!
```

Answer (score 0):

See comments for answer.
[Sorting a std::map by value before output & destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367429/sorting-a-stdmap-by-value-before-output-destroy)

After some modification (changing the for to only go to map.size()) it works perfect. Could people please vote to delete?